# Total Sum SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that collects many different columns, and I want to include a column that sums the price of every component in an order. Right now, I already have a column that simply shows the price of every component of an order, but I am not sure how to create this new column.

I would think that the code would go something like this, but I am not really clear on what an aggregate function is or why I get an error regarding the aggregate function when I try to run this code.

`SELECT ID, Location, Price, (SUM(PriceDescription) FROM table GROUP BY ID WHERE PriceDescription LIKE 'Cost.%' AS Summary)
FROM table`

When I say each component, I mean that every ID I have has many different items that make up the general price. I only want to find out how much money I spend on my supplies that I need for my pressure washers which is why I said `Where PriceDescription LIKE 'Cost.%'

To further explain, I have receipts of every customer I've worked with and in these receipts I write down my cost for the soap that I use and the tools for the pressure washer that I rent. I label all of these with 'Cost.' so it looks like (Cost.Water), (Cost.Soap), (Cost.Gas), (Cost.Tools) and I would like it so for Order 1 it there's a column that sums all the Cost.**_ prices for the order and for Order 2 it sums all the Cost._** prices for that order. I should also mention that each Order does not have the same number of Costs (sometimes when I use my power washer I might not have to buy gas and occasionally soap).

I hope this makes sense, if not please let me know how I can explain further.

```
`ID    Location    Price     PriceDescription
 1     Park        10        Cost.Water
 1     Park        8         Cost.Gas
 1     Park        11        Cost.Soap
 2     Tom         20        Cost.Water
 2     Tom         6         Cost.Soap
 3     Matt        15        Cost.Tools
 3     Matt        15        Cost.Gas
 3     Matt        21        Cost.Tools
 4     College     32        Cost.Gas
 4     College     22        Cost.Water
 4     College     11        Cost.Tools`
```

I would like for my query to create a column like such

```
`ID    Location    Price    Summary
 1     Park        10       29
 1     Park        8        
 1     Park        11       
 2     Tom         20       26
 2     Tom         6        
 3     Matt        15       51
 3     Matt        15       
 3     Matt        21       
 4     College     32       65
 4     College     22       
 4     College     11        `
```

But if the 'Summary' was printed on every line instead of just at the top one, that would be okay too.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I just added samples to my question

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly

Comment: @nola94 can you please check the answer

Comment: @mohan111 I am not sure if I can use two selects clauses when I am also using a union select to combine the same data I'm getting from my other store

Comment: but as of your posted question and sample data I have given answer

Comment: @mohan111 I am telling you that it won't work in my case, it might in others but not this one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just require sum(Price) over(Partition by Location) will give total sum as below:

```
SELECT ID, Location, Price, SUM(Price) over(Partition by Location) AS Summed_Price
   FROM yourtable
WHERE PriceDescription LIKE 'Cost.%'
```

Comment: This works for the most part, but it includes all the prices that make up the Order, not just the ones that start with Cost under PriceDescription

Comment: Just add the WHERE PriceDescription LIKE 'Cost.%' in and you would get your result.

Comment: @DVT when I try to add it in after 'AS Summed_Price, I get an error that says "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'."

Comment: SQL-Server syntax: your WHERE clause should be after your FROM clause.

Comment: Yep it has to be on the where clause

Answer (score 1):

First, if your `Price` column really contains values that match `'Cost.%'`, then you can not apply SUM() over it. SUM() expects a number (e.g. INT, FLOAT, REAL or DECIMAL). If it is text then you need to explicitly convert it to a number by adding a CAST or CONVERT clause inside the SUM() call.

Second, your query syntax is wrong: you need GROUP BY, and the SELECT fields are not specified correctly. And you want to SUM() the Price field, not the PriceDescription field (which you can't even sum as I explained)

Assuming that `Price` *is* numeric (see my first remark), then this is how it can be done:

```
SELECT ID
     , Location
     , Price
     , (SELECT SUM(Price)
        FROM table
        WHERE ID = T1.ID AND Location = T1.Location
       ) AS Summed_Price
FROM table AS T1
```

Comment: I have added a sample to my question of my data

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You can not have rows with prices *and* the sum; you have to choose. The query above will give 4 rows: 1 row for each combination of ID and Location.

Comment: So there is no way to break down the prices of an order and also show a sum?

Comment: Now I see, in that case you need to use a nested SELECT but you were doing it wrong.

Comment: Can you help me with that? I'm pretty foggy on nested SELECT and GROUP BY (I don't understand why you have to include all the columns in a group by when I just want it to group by ID)

Comment: It is required, just because it is... See my re-revised answer. It can be done without GROUP BY if there are no other columns in the SELECT that has the SUM.

Comment: If I decide to add another SUM column though, I would use "GROUP BY ID, Location" though, correct?

Comment: A nested SELECT can **[return only one column and one value](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-server-20-using-subqueries-in-the-select-statement/)**. And because of that it never needs a GROUP BY, which you only need if you have a SUM *and* other columns. The nested SELECT will almost always have a WHERE to couple it with the main query.

Answer (score 0):

to get exact result like posted in question

```
    Select  
                T.ID,
                T.Location,
                T.Price,
                CASE WHEN (R) = 1 then RN ELSE NULL  END Summary 
            from  (
    select 
                ID, 
                Location, 
                Price ,
                SUM(Price)OVER(PARTITION BY Location)RN,
                ROW_number()OVER(PARTITION BY Location ORDER BY ID )R 
            from  Table
     )T
order by T.ID
```